# Getting dictionary from psycopg2

Tags: python, database, dictionary, psycopg2

I have table which looks like this:

```
--------+-------+
      8 |     8 |
      8 |     9 |
      8 |    10 |
      8 |    11 |
      8 |    29 |
      8 |    30 |
      8 |    33 |
      8 |    34 |
      9 |     8 |
      9 |     9 |
      9 |    10 |
      9 |    11 |
      9 |    12 |
      9 |    13 |
      9 |    19 |
```

What I want to get in python is a dictionary with keys from the first column and the values are lists of second column (i.e. `dic[8]=[8,9,10,11,29,30,33,34]`).

Right now, I am getting a list of lists from the table and populating the dictionary myself but it wastes too much time.

What will be the most efficient way to to this?

Comment: What are you using to populate it yourself?

Comment: @JonClements Just looping over the list, checking if the key exists in dictionary.

Comment: Have you tried [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)?

Comment: Have you tried `select col1, array_agg(col2) from table_name group by col1` - that might do what you want on postgres' side

Comment: @JonClements 1 sec. :P

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary great minds think alike (but fools seldom differ) kind of thing? :p

Comment: Thanks for info about array_agg, both of you, this might do it.

Comment: @JonClements One of you(great minds), consider writing an answer.:)

Comment: Did it work? All yours if you want it @AshwiniChaudhary (bloomin' 1 sec!) :p

Comment: @JonClements Give me a second, if psycopg returns a list from `{...}`, it does work

Comment: @JonClements Nop, go ahead.

Comment: Well, I can't test it because I don't have a postgresql server handy... so not sure how the pyscopg2 adapter deals with arrays... they *might* become `list`s... @khajvah - I'm curious to know though :)

Comment: @JonClements I just tested it, it does become a list. PERFECT.

Comment: Awesome - I'll make a note of that for the future... anyway - answer done - cheers @Ashwini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing the aggregation on the client side, PostgreSQL supports an [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) function which you use with a `GROUP BY`, eg:

```
SELECT col1, array_agg(col2) FROM table_name GROUP BY col1
```

As long as you're only returning two columns, you can then use `dict` on the cursor/query, eg:

```
my_lookup = dict(cursor)
```